# How do i search a list of words using a list of letters in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of a hundred words or so and a list of eight letters how do i search each letter aginast the words finding out which word has the most letters from the list and then print that word.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm sorry, but I find it very hard to figure out what you are asking here. It would help if you included some code to show what you have tried, it'll make it much easier for us to help you. Perhaps you could also take a look at http://whathaveyoutried.com for a great article on how to ask good questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def searchWord(letters, word):
    count = 0
    for l in letters:
        count += word.count(l)

    return count

words = ['hello', 'world'];
letters = ['l', 'o']

currentWord  = None
currentCount = 0

for w in words:
    n = searchWord(letters, w)

    print "word:\t", w, " count:\t", n

    if n > currentCount:
        currentWord = w
        currentCount = n

print "highest word count:", currentWord
```

Answer (score 0):

Not super efficient, but you could do something like this:

```
def search(test, words):
    return sorted(((sum(1 for c in word if c in test), word) for word in words),
        reverse=True)
```

That'll give you a sorted list of words and counts.